# How Do I Determine Which Domain Has The Most Traffic?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web, traffic

My client is hosting like 500 domains. His senior sysop for some reason is unavailable. We're trying to figure out what command you type with Linux and Apache to determine which domains are taking up the most traffic.

You see, we need to block those top few domains because it's blocking traffic to all his other customers right now. It's the Digg effect, in a sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the easiest way to do this is to take the access logs for the last couple of hours and run them through an analytics program like webalizer or awstats.

There's no "one-shot" command you can run in apache to show you what traffic is like.

You may be able to install apachetop - this can give you some real-time information on what's going on, but if your sysadmin isn't around, I'm not sure it would be a great idea to install software on the server.

Another option would be to perhaps do a packet capture on the server for say, 15 minutes or so, and open up the capture file in wireshark. From there, you'll be able to analyze the HTTP headers to see which sites are being requested most often.

Comment: wtop is cool too.  http://code.google.com/p/wtop/

Comment: wtop and logrep look to be the ticket.

Comment: I use number of connection in access log as parameter. can we not calculate how much data transferred using access log.